# AngularJS textarea doesn't update

Tags: angularjs

I have this directive to be able to prevent characters of the textarea.

```
restrict: 'E',
    scope:{
      contacts : "="
    },
    template:'<textarea ng-model="contacts" ng-list=","><textarea>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
        scope.$watch('contacts', function(newValue, oldValue){
            var cut = newValue;
            if(newValue.length>0)
                var cut = newValue[newValue.length-1].replace(/\n|a|b|c/g, "");
            scope.contacts[scope.contacts.length-1] = cut;
        });
    }


<email-textarea contacts="contacts"></email-textarea>
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcelly/wrrqx60t/3/)

If I start typing, the contacts in the scope ignore the characters I set. But the textarea seems not to update its text. How can I update the textarea?

Comment: @raina77ow: you are right, it might be a problem because you cant add a object to a textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ng-list` doesn't watch over the collection' contents (and for some reason there seems to be no way of doing it without changing the source). So one possible way is watch over it in your own code:

```
scope.$watchCollection('contacts', function(newContacts){
  if (newContacts) {
    scope.contacts = newContacts.map(function(rec){
      return rec.replace(/[\nabc]/g, '');
    });
  }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qmftz4qz/). I'm using `watchCollection` here, because one should only fire watcher if *contents* of `contacts` array has changed - the array will be swapped each time a handler fires.

An alternative would be still using `watch`, but changing the array only if it has be changed because of invalid characters:

```
scope.$watch('contacts', function (newContacts) {
    var fixedContacts, shouldBeReplaced;
    if (newContacts) {
        fixedContacts = newContacts.map(function(rec) {
            var newRec = rec.replace(/[\nabc]/g, '');
            if (newRec !== rec) {
                shouldBeReplaced = true;
            }
            return newRec;
        });
        if (shouldBeReplaced) {
            scope.contacts = fixedContacts;
        }
    }
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kgws0b8s/).

Note that in both cases one has to watch over the whole list: you cannot guarantee that a user won't go back to the beginning of the list and start making changes there (or in any part of the text). That's why checking only the last element wasn't good enough.

Comment: Thanks, I just watched the last element for testing.
Watching the list is great, didn't knew this feature before :)